# Best Audio Player

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

- I want to make app based on Audio Player. I did work with AVAudioPlayer before. Now I want to know which is latest Audio Player available for ios. No matter what kind of integration is needed. But is it best among all available audio players? Should I go with AVAudioPlayer again or there is something other good in market?

In order to learn something new I'm asking this question otherwise AVAudioPlayer is good.

Any recommendation will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVAudioPlayer is good for audio but if you learn different then you can try with

mpmovieviewcontroller. I am also use it for play audio in one of my App. Actually it play

video also & audio too. For streaming type content (Like audio/video from web services or

from internet) then it is perfect player. And it also look like iPhone default player. Search

some tutorial on it & implement it. It is easily be implemented also. Best of luck.

Comment: I did work with mpmovieplayer also.But is there something different than these two?

Comment: No perhaps,but  I am always play with only these.